# Regex not capturing group that contains period

Tags: regex

I'm working a regex to match anything starting with a letter in a string similar to `G71P100Q110U0W0F.01`.  I've come up with `([A-Z].*?)(?=[A-Z])` which works fine until I reach `F.01` where it stops matching.  From what I've read, the `.*?` should match anything lazily but it's not.  What do I need to add to include the period?

Edit:

Desired matches for the string `G71P100Q110U0W0F.01` would be `G71`, `P100`, `Q110`, `U0`, `W0`, and `F.01`.  I can iterate through the matches easily enough in VBA.

Comment: You may use: `([A-Z].*?)(?=[A-Z.])`

Comment: Do you want anything _starting_ with a letter or anything _ending_ with a letter?  The lookahead at the end sort of implies the latter.

Comment: It stops at `P` unless you have applied *all* matches. You may try `([A-Z].*?)(?=[A-Z]|$)`

Comment: @tjb1 lots of options here but I think `[A-Z][^A-Z\s]+` is the most straightforward, answer below with code demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the lookahead: `(?=[A-Z])`. I.,e. your regex would be simplified to `([A-Z].*?)`

This lookahead makes sure that there will be at least one capital character after the end of `.*`. However, you already match a capital character at the beginning of your regex: `([A-Z]...)`. So you need two capital characters, but you have only one.

Unfortunately, I don't understand the rules on what you want and don't want to match. It would be cool to have more examples both for matching and not matching strings.

Probably this regex would be good for you:

```
([A-Z].*?)\.[0-9]+
```

It makes sure that your text:

- starts with a capital letter
- ends with a dot, and then one or more numbers

[**Demo here**](https://regex101.com/r/oTecwR/1).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is:

```
[A-Z][^A-Z]*
```

Match an uppercase letter then anything but an uppercase letter.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/9H8h6F/1)

> From what I've read, the `.*?` should match anything lazily...

and it's the exact thing that's happening. It stops right after it finds following character is an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`[A-Z]\.?[0-9]+`

Period must be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for a regex pattern that matches a sequence of non-space character(s) starting with a letter:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]\S*
```

Answer (score 0):

`[A-Z][^A-Z\s]+`

- `[A-Z]` match a single letter
- `[^A-Z\s]+` match anything that's not whitespace or a letter

Run code sample for demo

```js
var input = "G71P100Q110U0W0F.01"
console.log(input.match(/[A-Z][^A-Z\s]+/g))
```